# Selecting multiple slices from a numpy array at once

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm looking for a way to select multiple slices from a numpy array at once. Say we have a 1D data array and want to extract three portions of it like below:

```
data_extractions = []

for start_index in range(0, 3):
    data_extractions.append(data[start_index: start_index + 5])
```

Afterwards `data_extractions` will be:

```
data_extractions = [
    data[0:5],
    data[1:6],
    data[2:7]
]
```

Is there any way to perform above operation without the for loop? Some sort of indexing scheme in numpy that would let me select multiple slices from an array and return them as that many arrays, say in an n+1 dimensional array?

---

I thought maybe I can replicate my data and then select a span from each row, but code below throws an IndexError

```
replicated_data = np.vstack([data] * 3)
data_extractions = replicated_data[[range(3)], [slice(0, 5), slice(1, 6), slice(2, 7)]
```

Comment: What's `n` there?

Comment: `stride_tricks` might be a way

Comment: @Divakar - dimension. I gave a 1D example for simplicity, but need a generic solution (my real problem is 4D).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the indexes to select the rows you want into the appropriate shape.
For example:

```
 data = np.random.normal(size=(100,2,2,2))

 # Creating an array of row-indexes
 indexes = np.array([np.arange(0,5), np.arange(1,6), np.arange(2,7)])
 # data[indexes] will return an element of shape (3,5,2,2,2). Converting
 # to list happens along axis 0
 data_extractions = list(data[indexes])

 np.all(data_extractions[1] == data[1:6])
 True
```

The final comparison is against the original data.

Comment: Damn it, I tried above approach but with `indexes` as list of ranges as well as list of slices and these would cause `IndexErrors`. Didn't realize I need to wrap outer list of `indexes` in a numpy array ^^

Comment: I think when you put a list into the `numpy` selector, it tries to filter per axis (i.e., the first item is filter for the first axis etc). Actually, putting it inside another list, as in `indexes = [[np.arange(0,5), np.arange(1,6), np.arange(2,7)]]` solves it.

Answer (score 10):

`stride_tricks` can do that

```
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (3, 5), 2 * a.strides)
b
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Please note that `b` references the same memory as `a`, in fact multiple times (for example `b[0, 1]` and `b[1, 0]` are the same memory address). It is therefore safest to make a copy before working with the new structure.

nd can be done in a similar fashion, for example 2d -> 4d

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (3,3,2,2), 2*a.strides)
b.reshape(9,2,2) # this forces a copy
# array([[[ 0,  1],
#         [ 4,  5]],

#        [[ 1,  2],
#         [ 5,  6]],

#        [[ 2,  3],
#         [ 6,  7]],

#        [[ 4,  5],
#         [ 8,  9]],

#        [[ 5,  6],
#         [ 9, 10]],

#        [[ 6,  7],
#         [10, 11]],

#        [[ 8,  9],
#         [12, 13]],

#        [[ 9, 10],
#         [13, 14]],

#        [[10, 11],
#         [14, 15]]])
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, thank you, Paul.

Comment: @Puchatek glad to be of help. Just be careful with that stuff. As far as I know it doesn't check ranges, so it will happily allow you to access out-of-range memory etc.

Comment: Yep, toyed around with it in Ipython and realized quickly it can blow in my face when used carelessly ^^

Comment: @Puchatek If you are using proper shapes and strides, should be okay.

Answer (score 7):

In this post is an approach with `strided-indexing scheme` using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) that basically creates a view into the input array and as such is pretty efficient for creation and being a view occupies nomore memory space.
Also, this works for ndarrays with generic number of dimensions.

Here's the implementation -

```
def strided_axis0(a, L):
    # Store the shape and strides info
    shp = a.shape
    s  = a.strides

    # Compute length of output array along the first axis
    nd0 = shp[0]-L+1

    # Setup shape and strides for use with np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    # and get (n+1) dim output array
    shp_in = (nd0,L)+shp[1:]
    strd_in = (s[0],) + s
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shp_in, strides=strd_in)
```

Sample run for a `4D` array case -

```
In [44]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(10,4,2,3)) # Array

In [45]: L = 5      # Window length along the first axis

In [46]: out = strided_axis0(a, L)

In [47]: np.allclose(a[0:L], out[0])  # Verify outputs
Out[47]: True

In [48]: np.allclose(a[1:L+1], out[1])
Out[48]: True

In [49]: np.allclose(a[2:L+2], out[2])
Out[49]: True
```

Answer (score 6):

In the general case you have to do some sort of iteration - and concatenation - either when constructing the indexes or when collecting the results.  It's only when the slicing pattern is itself regular that you can use a generalized slicing via `as_strided`.

The accepted answer constructs an indexing array, one row per slice.  So that is iterating over the slices, and `arange` itself is a (fast) iteration.  And `np.array` concatenates them on a new axis (`np.stack` generalizes this).

```
In [264]: np.array([np.arange(0,5), np.arange(1,6), np.arange(2,7)])
Out[264]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

`indexing_tricks` convenience methods to do the same thing:

```
In [265]: np.r_[0:5, 1:6, 2:7]
Out[265]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

This takes the slicing notation, expands it with `arange` and concatenates.  It even lets me expand and concatenate  into 2d

```
In [269]: np.r_['0,2',0:5, 1:6, 2:7]
Out[269]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

In [270]: data=np.array(list('abcdefghijk'))
In [272]: data[np.r_['0,2',0:5, 1:6, 2:7]]
Out[272]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
       ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
       ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']], 
      dtype='<U1')
In [273]: data[np.r_[0:5, 1:6, 2:7]]
Out[273]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e',
       'f', 'g'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Concatenating results after indexing also works.

```
In [274]: np.stack([data[0:5],data[1:6],data[2:7]])
```

My memory from other SO questions is that relative timings are in the same order of magnitude.  It may vary for example with the number of slices versus their length.  Overall the number of values that have to be copied from source to target will be the same.

If the slices vary in length, you'd have to use the flat indexing.

Comment: Luckily I have to deal with slicing according to a regular pattern.
Thank you for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You can slice your array with a prepared slicing array

```
a = np.array(list('abcdefg'))

b = np.array([
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    ])

a[b]
```

However, `b` doesn't have to generated by hand in this way. It can be more dynamic with

```
b = np.arange(5) + np.arange(3)[:, None]
```

Comment: So I though about this approach but couldn't get it to work because didn't wrap list of lists making indices into a numpy array. Silly me I guess.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which approach you choose, if 2 slices contain same element, it doesn't support mathematical operations correctly unlesss you use `ufunc.at` which can be more inefficient than loop. For testing:

```py
def as_strides(arr, window_size, stride, writeable=False):
    '''Get a strided sub-matrices view of a 4D ndarray.

    Args:
        arr (ndarray): input array with shape (batch_size, m1, n1, c).
        window_size (tuple): with shape (m2, n2).
        stride (tuple): stride of windows in (y_stride, x_stride).
        writeable (bool): it is recommended to keep it False unless needed
    Returns:
        subs (view): strided window view, with shape (batch_size, y_nwindows, x_nwindows, m2, n2, c)

    See also numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view
    '''
    batch_size = arr.shape[0]
    m1, n1, c = arr.shape[1:]
    m2, n2 = window_size
    y_stride, x_stride = stride

    view_shape = (batch_size, 1 + (m1 - m2) // y_stride,
                  1 + (n1 - n2) // x_stride, m2, n2, c)
    strides = (arr.strides[0], y_stride * arr.strides[1],
               x_stride * arr.strides[2]) + arr.strides[1:]
    subs = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr,
                                           view_shape,
                                           strides=strides,
                                           writeable=writeable)
    return subs


import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

Xs = as_strides(np.random.randn(1, 5, 5, 2), (3, 3), (2, 2), writeable=True)[0]
print('input\n0,0\n', Xs[0, 0])
np.add.at(Xs, np.s_[:], 5)
print('unbuffered sum output\n0,0\n', Xs[0,0])
np.add.at(Xs, np.s_[:], -5)
Xs = Xs + 5
print('normal sum output\n0,0\n', Xs[0, 0])
```

Answer (score -2):

We can use list comprehension for this

```
data=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
data_extractions=[data[b:b+5] for b in [1,2,3,4,5]]
data_extractions
```

Results

```
[array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10])]
```

Comment: That doesn't avoid a for loop ;)

Comment: I agree :) but not a native for loop :)