# How do you efficiently access multiple slices from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Currently I am accessing multiple slices as follows:

First, I allocate an array that will be re-assigned many times

```
X = np.zeros( (batch_size, window, 5) )
```

This is the assignment loop that will be run multiple times (`batch_indices` has different indices each time but the same shape):

```
for i, b in enumerate(batch_indices):
    X[i] = Xs[b:b+window]
```

Is there a more efficient way? I feel like there should be syntax similar to:

```
X = Xs[ [slice(b,b+window) for b in batch_indices] ]
```

While the shape of `Xs` is 2-dimensional, the final shape of X should be a 3-dimensional np.array. Think of it as follows: `Xs` is one long multi-dimensional time-series, and X needs to be a numpy array containing many slices of the multi-dimensional time-series.

Comment: have you looked into [numpy iterations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html)?

Comment: have you try boolean indexes? worth a performance check...

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

One vectorized approach would be to create all those  sliding windowed indices and index into `Xs` with those, like so -

```
X = Xs[np.asarray(batch_indices)[:,None] + np.arange(window)]
```

---

**Approach #2**

Another memory efficient approach would be to create `sliding-windows` with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides), thus avoiding the creation of the sliding windowed indices as done in the previous approach and simply index with `batch_indices`, like so -

```
X = strided_axis0(Xs,window)[np.asarray(batch_indices)]
```

Strides based function `strided_axis0` is from [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413801/3293881).