# Arnaud Legoux Moving Average (ALMA) in NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I'd like to write the vectored version of code that calculates Arnaud Legoux Moving Average (ALMA) using NumPy (or Pandas). Could you help me with this, please? Thanks.

Non-vectored version looks like following (see below).

```
def NPALMA(pnp_array, **kwargs) :
    '''
    ALMA - Arnaud Legoux Moving Average,
    http://www.financial-hacker.com/trend-delusion-or-reality/
    https://github.com/darwinsys/Trading_Strategies/blob/master/ML/Features.py
    '''
    length = kwargs['length']
    # just some number (6.0 is useful)
    sigma = kwargs['sigma']
    # sensisitivity (close to 1) or smoothness (close to 0)
    offset = kwargs['offset']

    asize = length - 1
    m = offset * asize
    s = length  / sigma
    dss = 2 * s * s
    
    alma = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)
    wtd_sum = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)

    for l in range(len(pnp_array)):
        if l >= asize:
            for i in range(length):
                im = i - m
                wtd = np.exp( -(im * im) / dss)
                alma[l] += pnp_array[l - length + i] * wtd
                wtd_sum[l] += wtd
            alma[l] = alma[l] / wtd_sum[l]

    return alma
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Starting Approach**

We can create sliding windows along the first axis and then use tensor multiplication with the range of `wtd` values for the sum-reductions.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
# Get all wtd values in an array
wtds = np.exp(-(np.arange(length) - m)**2/dss)

# Get the sliding windows for input array along first axis
pnp_array3D = strided_axis0(pnp_array,len(wtds))

# Initialize o/p array
out = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)

# Get sum-reductions for the windows which don't need wrapping over
out[length:] = np.tensordot(pnp_array3D,wtds,axes=((1),(0)))[:-1]

# Last element of the output needed wrapping. So, do it separately.
out[length-1] = wtds.dot(pnp_array[np.r_[-1,range(length-1)]])

# Finally perform the divisions
out /= wtds.sum()
```

Function to get the sliding windows : `strided_axis0` is from [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413801/3293881).

**Boost with `1D` convolution**

Those multiplications with `wtds` values and then their sum-reductions are basically convolution along the first axis. As such, we can use [`scipy.ndimage.convolve1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve1d.html) along `axis=0`. This would be much faster given the memory efficiency, as we won't be creating huge sliding windows.

The implementation would be -

```
from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d as conv

avgs = conv(pnp_array, weights=wtds/wtds.sum(),axis=0, mode='wrap')
```

Thus, `out[length-1:]`, which are the non-zero rows would be same as `avgs[:-length+1]`.

There could be some precision difference if we are working with really small kernel numbers from `wtds`. So, keep that in mind if using this `convolution` method.

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def original_app(pnp_array, length, m, dss):
    alma = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)
    wtd_sum = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)

    for l in range(len(pnp_array)):
        if l >= asize:
            for i in range(length):
                im = i - m
                wtd = np.exp( -(im * im) / dss)
                alma[l] += pnp_array[l - length + i] * wtd
                wtd_sum[l] += wtd
            alma[l] = alma[l] / wtd_sum[l]
    return alma

def vectorized_app1(pnp_array, length, m, dss):
    wtds = np.exp(-(np.arange(length) - m)**2/dss)
    pnp_array3D = strided_axis0(pnp_array,len(wtds))
    out = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)
    out[length:] = np.tensordot(pnp_array3D,wtds,axes=((1),(0)))[:-1]
    out[length-1] = wtds.dot(pnp_array[np.r_[-1,range(length-1)]])
    out /= wtds.sum()
    return out

def vectorized_app2(pnp_array, length, m, dss):
    wtds = np.exp(-(np.arange(length) - m)**2/dss)
    return conv(pnp_array, weights=wtds/wtds.sum(),axis=0, mode='wrap')
```

Timings -

```
In [470]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: m,n = 1000,100
     ...: pnp_array = np.random.rand(m,n)
     ...: 
     ...: length = 6
     ...: sigma = 0.3
     ...: offset = 0.5
     ...: 
     ...: asize = length - 1
     ...: m = np.floor(offset * asize)
     ...: s = length  / sigma
     ...: dss = 2 * s * s
     ...: 

In [471]: %timeit original_app(pnp_array, length, m, dss)
     ...: %timeit vectorized_app1(pnp_array, length, m, dss)
     ...: %timeit vectorized_app2(pnp_array, length, m, dss)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 36.1 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 684 µs per loop

In [472]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: m,n = 10000,1000 # rest same as previous one

In [473]: %timeit original_app(pnp_array, length, m, dss)
     ...: %timeit vectorized_app1(pnp_array, length, m, dss)
     ...: %timeit vectorized_app2(pnp_array, length, m, dss)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 503 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 222 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop
```

Comment: I've checked your second approach with 1d convolution. And it looks like there is something wrong with it. But I can't get what exactly.
My example:
pnp_array=np.array([ 3924.00752506 , 5774.30335369 , 5519.40734814 , 4931.71344059])
offset=0.85
sigma=6
length=3
m=1.7
dss=0.5

Expected result should be [0 , 0, 5594.17030842 , 5115.59420056]. But second application returns [ 0 , 0 , 5693.3358598 , 5333.61073335]. So cummulative error is -317.182084168.
Is this because of small kernel numbers as you mentioned?

Comment: @Prokhozhii What are the values of  `wtds` from `wtds = np.exp(-(np.arange(length) - m)**2/dss)` for that set?

Comment: They are correct in second application:
array([ 0.00308872,  0.3753111 ,  0.83527021])

Comment: @Prokhozhii I know those are correct. I am asking for their values to get a sense of how they compare against values in `pnp_array`. If those are much smaller, then yes please use app#1. Okay, so they look very small, so yes please app#1 for such cases. It's the same precision issue I talked about.

Comment: As far as I understand app#1 has error with indexes. It returns
[ 0,  0, 5199.97996566, 5594.17030842]. But 4th element should be third and 5th element, which is absent, should be 4th. Can you help with this, please?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong (I'm newbie in NumPy) but following code works correctly in my case:


`def vectorized_app1(pnp_array, length, m, dss):
    wtds = np.exp( -(np.arange(length) - m)**2 / dss )
    pnp_array3D = strided_axis0(pnp_array, len(wtds))
    
    out = np.zeros(pnp_array.shape)
    
    out[length-1:] = np.tensordot( pnp_array3D , wtds , axes=( (1), (0) ) ) [:]
    
    out /= wtds.sum()
    return out`

Answer (score 1):

None of the variations in the previous answer by Divakar quite matched the numbers produced by TradingView's ALMA v26.0. It is essential that the numbers match a reference. With this goal in mind, the [Pine Script v5 implementation of `ta.alma`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dalma) serves as a reference even though it is not vectorized.

Here is a NumPy version which produces the same outputs as TradingView:

```py
import numpy as np

def alma_np(prices: np.ndarray, window: int = 9, sigma: float = 6, offset: float = 0.85) -> np.ndarray:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76031340/
    m = offset * (window - 1)
    s = window / sigma
    i = np.arange(window)
    weights = np.exp(-1 * np.square(i - m) / (2 * np.square(s)))
    norm_weights = weights / np.sum(weights)
    padded_prices = np.pad(prices, (window - 1, 0), mode='edge')
    alma_values = np.convolve(padded_prices, norm_weights[::-1], mode='valid')
    return alma_values
```

Here is a Pandas version which uses the above NumPy version:

```py
def alma_pd(prices: pd.Series, window: int = 9, *, sigma: float = 6, offset: float = 0.85) -> pd.Series:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76031340/
    prices_series = prices
    prices = prices.to_numpy()
    alma_values = alma_np(prices, window, sigma=sigma, offset=offset)
    alma_series = pd.Series(alma_values, index=prices_series.index)
    return alma_series
```

The values were cross-checked over 5min data for $SPY for 2023-04-14, matching to the fifth decimal place.