# Select different slices from each numpy row

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-indexing

I have a 3d tensor and I want to select different slices from the dim=2. something like `a[[0, 1], :, [slice(2, 4), slice(1, 3)]]`.

```py
a=np.arange(2*3*5).reshape(2, 3, 5)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])
# then I want something like a[[0, 1], :, [slice(2, 4), slice(1, 3)]]
# that gives me np.stack([a[0, :, 2:4], a[1, :, 1:3]]) without a for loop
array([[[ 2,  3],
        [ 7,  8],
        [12, 13]],

       [[16, 17],
        [21, 22],
        [26, 27]]])
```

and I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413582/selecting-multiple-slices-from-a-numpy-array-at-once) and it is not what I want.

Comment: Why don't you want the linked answers?  Do you disagree with my claim that some sort of loop is necessary?  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`advanced indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) as explained here. You will have to pass the row ids which are `[0, 1]` in your case and the column ids `2, 3` and `1, 2`. Here `2,3` means `[2:4]` and `1, 2` means `[1:3]`

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(2*3*5).reshape(2, 3, 5)

rows = np.array([[0], [1]], dtype=np.intp)
cols = np.array([[2, 3], [1, 2]], dtype=np.intp)

aa = np.stack(a[rows, :, cols]).swapaxes(1, 2)
# array([[[ 2,  3],
#         [ 7,  8],
#         [12, 13]],

#        [[16, 17],
#         [21, 22],
#         [26, 27]]])
```

Another equivalent way to avoid `swapaxes` and getting the result in desired format is

```
aa = np.stack(a[rows, :, cols], axis=2).T
```

A third way I figured out is by passing the list of indices. Here `[0, 0]` will correspond to `[2,3]` and `[1, 1]` will correspond to `[1, 2]`. The `swapaxes` is just to get your desired format of output

```
a[[[0,0], [1,1]], :, [[2,3], [1,2]]].swapaxes(1,2)
```

Comment: You have converted the slices into advanced indexing arrays - which in the general case will require a loop on the slices and expanding them with `arange` (or `r_`).  It should also be mentioned that the `swapaxes` is required because your indexing still has a slice in the middle - and that dimension is 'tacked on' to the end (a case of combined advance and basic indexing).

Answer (score -1):

A solution...

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(2*3*5).reshape(2, 3, 5)
np.array([a[0,:,2:4], a[1,:,1:3]])
```