# Index numpy array with multiple ranges

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Imagine an array `a` which has to be indexed by multiple ranges in `idx`:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([7,9,1,2,3,5,6,8,1,0,])
        idx = np.array([[0,3],[5,7],[8,9]])

        a, idx

Out[1]: (array([7, 9, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 1, 0]),
         array([[0, 3],
                [5, 7],
                [8, 9]]))
```

Of course I could write a simple `for` loop, which results in the desired output:

```
In [2]: np.hstack([a[i[0]:i[1]] for i in idx])

Out[2]: array([7, 9, 1, 5, 6, 1])
```

But I would like a fully vectorized approach. I was hoping `np.r_` for example would provide a solution. But the code below does **not** result in the desired output:

```
In [3]: a[np.r_[idx]]

Out[3]: array([[7, 2],
               [5, 8],
               [1, 0]])
```

Whereas writing out `idx` does result in the desired output. But the real life `idx` is too large to write out:

```
In [4]: a[np.r_[0:3,5:7,8:9]]

Out[4]: array([7, 9, 1, 5, 6, 1])
```

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413582/selecting-multiple-slices-from-a-numpy-array-at-once

Comment: Thanks for helping! The problem is, in real life ```idx``` can become really large so writing it out would not be an option

Comment: Don't use functions like `np.r_` on a **hope**.  Read the docs.  I tried to cover all your options in the linked SO.  Either you concatenate the values after slicing, or concatenate the slices before indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj My hope on ```np.r_``` was based on that writing out ```idx``` like ```a[np.r_[0:3,5:7,8:9]]``` does actually give the desired output, but that I just didn't know how to use the ```idx``` 2D array directly on ```np.r_```. Anyways, thanks for helping! However, I am not really sure where to find the 'linked SO' you describe?

Answer (score 0):

You can try vectorizing `slice` itself:

```
>>> slice_np = np.vectorize(slice)
>>> slice_idx = tuple(slice_np(idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]))
>>> a[np.r_[slice_idx]]
 array([7, 9, 1, 5, 6, 1])
```

Comment: `np.hstack([np.arange(i,j) for i,j in idx])` is a faster way of generating the indices.

Comment: @hpaulj does it scale? For example `idx = np.vstack([idx]*1000)`

Comment: You could do some of your own time testing, but there are a lot of variations to explore.  For the larger `idx` `slice_np` does scale somewhat better.  But if `idx` is a list, instead of an array, the list comprehension does better, even with large `idx`.  The other trade off is between OP's concatenate after index, versus your concatenate indices.  As I noted in the linked SO, those alternatives tend to time about the same.  There isn't a true "vectorized" option, one that moves all the iteration to compiled code.

Comment: I just read your answer. Your point is taken.